# javafx : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: javafx-2

i'm new to javafx and i want to load an fxml file to Pane

the problem is when i click to the  pageTwo button an exception message says that **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PageTwoController**

here is the code

```
@FXML
private void pageTwoAction(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("pageTwo.fxml"));
        Pane displayArea = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you included jar containing `PageTwoController` in classpath ??

Comment: the pageTwoController class exists on the same package where the main class, i thing there is no need the import it

Comment: How do you link to it in your fxml? Absolute/relative path?

Comment: @younes, you should include in your question your FXML and controller.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things the FXML must be aware of:

1. The controller class name **with** package path

`<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="countrycode.compoany.project.javafx.PageTwoController">`

2. Imports of all needed classes like in a normal java class file

`<?import countrycode.company.project.javafx.*?>`

You can either edit them manually or use SceneBuilder especially if you are new to JavaFX it helps a lot in the start

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NetBeans, you need to write yourself the import statement of the package in the .fxml file

```
<?import foldername.*?>
```